Attach Youtube video to liveStream and bind with liveBroadcast?
I'm currently working in Python on a project where I need to attach an existing video to a live stream that I created (liveStream.insert) and then bind a broadcast (liveBroadcast.insert and liveBroadcast.bind) to the liveStream on YouTube. I've been exploring the YouTube Data API and the YouTube Live Streaming API, but I'm unsure about the exact steps and API endpoints to achieve this.
Could someone please provide guidance how to attach an existing uploaded video from my channel to liveStream? I am able to bind liveBroadcast to liveStream, but I don't know how to connect existing video to liveStream.
Is it possible to do that like this or I should transfer video to liveStream differently? If it's not possible to transfer uploaded video to liveStream what other options I have?
I tried to bind liveBroadcast to existing video from my channel, but it is not possible. So I bind to liveStream, but I don't know how to transfer data from existing uploaded video to liveStream.
